# how to get the minimum scroll thumb height in javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am trying to get the minimum height of the div scroll thumb in javascript,
It looks like there is a minimum height that the browsers do not pass.
in chrome it is 16 px.
i need a formula to get it for all browsers
i am able to get the height if greater or equal to the minimum 
Can you help?

https://i.stack.imgur.com/A0NhD.png

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note that it's really dependent on the browser and often the browser uses native OS widgets, and DPI settings. On mobile devices the scrollbar is usually hidden entirely.

Whichever "solution" you'll find, you shouldn't trust it to work everywhere. Even if you'd cover all cases now, it most likely breaks tomorrow.